# javaScript Debugging Code Explanation

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am new to javaScript.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example</title>

<style>
body { "background-color: #fff; color: #000; font-size: 14px; 
position: relative;}
form {
font-size:16px;
}
</style>

</head>

<!-- Embedded css style -->
<body>

<div>  
<header>
<h1>Example</h1>
</header>

<div class= "container">
<main> 
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>
Example
</legend>
<!--asks for name-->
<label for="nameInput">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="nameInput" name="name" placeholder="John Doe" />

<br>

<!--asks for purchase price -->
<label for="amt">Amount:</label>
<input type="text" id="amt"><br>

<!--asks for state-->
<input type="radio" name="stateCode" value="k" id="k" checked> Kansas
<input type="radio" name="stateCode" value="c" id="c"> California
<input type="radio" name="stateCode" value="m" id="m">Missouri

<br>

<label for="tax">Tax :</label>
<input type="text" id="tax" disabled><br>

<label for="totalCost">Your total is:</label>
<input type="text" id="totalCost" disabled><br>

<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate"><br>  
</fieldset>
</form>

</main>

</div><!-- end .container -->
</div><!--end of #pushDown -->
</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
// returns a html element (id)
var $ = function(id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
};

// calculates total after sales tax
function coffeeCalc(amt,tax) {
var totalCost = amt + tax; 
totalCost = totalCost.toFixed(2); // 2 decimals
return totalCost; // returns value
}

function init() {
// assign variables to id and class values from HTML page
var amt = parseFloat( $("amt").value); 

// declaring variables
var taxRate;
var stateSelected; // for console log purpose only 

// radio buttons
if ($("k").checked) { 
taxRate = .087; // tax rate: 8.7%
stateSelected = "Kansas";
} else if ($("c").checked) { 
taxRate = .077; // tax rate: 7.7%
stateSelected = "California";
} else {
taxRate = .09; // tax rate: 9%
stateSelected = "Missouri";
}

var tax = amt * taxRate;

// shows output 
$("tax").value = tax.toFixed(2); // 2 decimals
$("totalCost").value = coffeeCalc(amt,tax); //calls the coffeeCalc function 
}
```

Image 1: 
On the bottom right side: it shows totalCost: input#totalCost.  The debugger displays amt: 10, so therefore I would think it would resemble amt except it should be: 
total: 10.87.
[image: Total Cost]

Image 2: After I finish debugging the last line:
console.log(“Total Cost: “ + $(“totalCost).value); 
it opens a new tab: VM236 with amt
What does that mean?
[image: After done debugging]

Comment: you're not changing `amt` in your code, it's whatever is entered in `$("amt")`

Comment: your fiddle does NOTHING on clicking calculate, by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `totalCost` in your screenshot refers to the DOM element, not the value from the `coffeeCalc` function, since that has already completed by the time your breakpoint has been reached (and the `totalCost` variable is locally scoped to that function).

You can see by typing `totalCost` into the console (without having broken) that there is a globally-scoped variable called `totalCost`, the value of which is the input element. [(See screenshot here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a29lX.png)

Regarding the new tab, the debugger is simply continuing to step through code that's running. VM... files are generated by Chrome's Dev Tools for scripts that have no sourceURL (that have been injected dynamically).

You say you are new to JS, so if you haven't already, you might want to take a look Chrome's official ['Getting Started'](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) guide to debugging.

Comment: How come amt and tax is not amt: input#amt  and tax: input#tax in the first screenshot?

Comment: That's because local variables called `amt` & `tax` have been declared and defined inside the `init` function.

In the screenshot, your breakpoint is inside your `init` function, and so the watch section is showing you the current values of those variables. `totalCost`, on the other hand, is not declared in `init`, but rather in `coffeeCalc`.

So, for `amt` & `tax` you're seeing the local variables which were defined in the function, but the value of `totalCost` has no local declaration in this context, so it falls back to the global variable, containing the DOM element.

Does that help?

Comment: It all comes down to the variable scope for your variables. For more info see: [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/) or [here](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it. :)